# Lagrangian of symplectic form stable by a torus in a rational representation

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, algebraic-number-theory

Let $\mathbb{K}_1$ and $\mathbb{K}_2$ be two number fields embedded in $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{K}_1\mathbb{K}_2$ be the field generated by the two. Let $k_1,k_2,k$ be their degrees.

Let $\mathbb{H}_1$ and $\mathbb{H}_2$ be two quaternion division algebras defined over $\mathbb{K}_1$ and $\mathbb{K}_2$ respectively and the semisimple $\mathbb{Q}$-algebraic group $G=SL_1(\mathbb{H}_1(\mathbb{K}_1))\times SL_1(\mathbb{H}_2(\mathbb{K}_2))$.

I'm interested in the $\mathbb{Q}$-irreducible representation of $G$ corresponding to the standard representations of $SL_1(\mathbb{H}_1(\mathbb{K}_1))$ and $SL_1(\mathbb{H}_2(\mathbb{K}_2))$.

One way to construct this representation is to consider a quadratic extension $\mathbb{K}(\alpha)$ that embeds in both $\mathbb{H}_1(\mathbb{K})$ and $\mathbb{H}_2(\mathbb{K})$ (there exists infinitely many such extensions), then $\mathbb{H}_{1,2}(\mathbb{K})$ are right $\mathbb{K}(\alpha)$-vector spaces and we consider the space
$$V = \mathbb{H}_1(\mathbb{K}) \otimes_{\mathbb{K}(\alpha)} \mathbb{H}_2(\mathbb{K})$$
on which $G$ acts on the left.

The action of $G$ on $V$ preserves $3$ linearly independant $\mathbb{K}$-quadratic forms and $1$ $\mathbb{K}$-symplectic form $w$.
I'd like to know if we can always find a lagrangian of $w$ stable by a maximal torus of $G$.

When $\mathbb{K}_1=\mathbb{K}_2=\mathbb{K}$, it is true : the action of $SL_1(\mathbb{H}_1(\mathbb{K}))$ on $\mathbb{H}_1(\mathbb{K})$ preserves a $\mathbb{K}(\alpha)/\mathbb{K}$-hermitian form $N_1$ (namely, the quaternionic norm), the same goes for $SL_1(\mathbb{H}_2(\mathbb{K}))$ on $\mathbb{H}_2(\mathbb{K})$ and the action of $G$ on $V$ preserves the tensor product $N_1 \otimes N_2$. The imaginary part of this hermitian form is our symplectic form $w$ and if we take $J_1$, (resp. $J_2$) in $\mathbb{H}_1(\mathbb{K})$ (resp. $\mathbb{H}_2(\mathbb{K})$) to be orthogonal to the chosen embedding of $\mathbb{K}(\alpha)$, then the subpsace $L$ of $V$ given by
$$L= \mathbb{K}(J_1) \otimes_{\mathbb{K}} \mathbb{K}(J_2)$$
is a lagrangian for $w$, stable by the torus of $G$ of lie algebra $(J_1,J_2)$.

When $\mathbb{K}_1 \neq \mathbb{K_2}$, the issue is that one may not be able to find $J_1$ in $\mathbb{H}_1(\mathbb{K}_1)$ (we find it in $\mathbb{H}_1(\mathbb{K})$). If the result is true, a different construction is required.